# How to access nested JSON objects via Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, object

as I'm still learning, after hours of trying I still couldn't work out how to manage this Ajax call in my WP and get it to work. What I want to do is extract the "price" (USD) into a variable for further use.

This is my JSON object:

```
{
"data": {
    "id": xx, 
    "name": "xx", 
    "symbol": "xx", 
    "rank": xx, 
    "quotes": {
        "USD": {
            "price": xx, 
            "volume_24h": xx, 
            "market_cap": xx, 
            "percent_change_1h": xx, 
        }
     }, 
     "last_updated": xx
  }, 
}
```

And here's what I'm currently doing:

```
(function(getPrice) {
    $j.ajax({
        url: 'https://widgets.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/3012/',
        type: 'GET',
        async: false,
        data: 'data',
    }).then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
})();
```

This gets me to log the whole "data", but after Google and StackOverflow I am still stuck. I figured it was just "data.quotes.USD.price", but apparently it isn't.

I would be very thankful vor every advice!

Comment: Your variable name is `data` and the first property of the object is also `data`, so the access would start off as `data.data`.  This is, of course, provided that the ajax method already parsed the response, otherwise you need to `JSON.parse(data)` first

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `data` twice; one is your variable, one is the outer object in the response. The correct version would be:

```
console.log(data.data.quotes.USD.price);
```

```js
var $j = jQuery;

(function(getPrice) {
  $j.ajax({
    url: 'https://widgets.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/3012/',
    type: 'GET',
  }).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data.data.quotes.USD.price);
  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Also note that I removed `async: false` (as it's terrible practice) and `data: 'data'` was not needed.

Comment: Wow. I feel incredibly stupid right now, because I have tried every possible version and nothing worked, though I would've never thought of that. So here's to me ugh. And thank you so so so much! (I would have never guessed this either.) I'll learn. Maybe. Someday.

Comment: @ClopinTrouillefou - We've all been there! You may consider using another variable name such as `response` instead, such as `then(function(response){` - You'll then have a semantically easier to read output: `response.data.quotes.USD.price`.